# Stackoverflow inside thread - stopwatch java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, stack-overflow

I would like to create a stopwatch as an android app. My problem is that I got a stackoverflow. Basically I have a class Timer and an onCreate method that instatiate it. Thats my implementation:

```
public abstract class Timer implements Runnable {

    private boolean running;

    public void start(){
        running = true;
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long milliSeconds = 0;
        long seconds = 0;
        long minutes = 0;

        long baseTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        while(running){
            long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - baseTime;
            long rest = time % 60000;
            milliSeconds = rest % 1000;
            seconds = rest - milliSeconds;
            minutes = time - seconds - milliSeconds;
            display(milliSeconds, seconds, minutes);
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        running = false;
    }

    public abstract void display(long milliSeconds, long seconds, long minutes);

}
```

And my onCreate method:

```
public TextView time;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.opslimit);

        time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Timer timer = new Timer(){
            @Override
            public void display(long milliSeconds, long seconds, long minutes) {
                time.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + milliSeconds);
            }
        };

        timer.start();        
}
```

Has anyone an idea why I got a Stackoverflow. May be it deals with the display part?

Answer (score 3):

You call `start` method recursively within itself. Fix it, and you won't get SO exception.

Note, however, that even if you change to :

```
    public void start(){
        running = true;
        this.run();
    }
```

which will fix stackoverflow, your code will run in a main thread and therefore your app won't work. You have to spawn a new thread.

I really suggest you use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)  - it will be clean code and less boilerplate threading, check example at the link.

You can, however, make your code work by doing this changes :

1. make `Timer extends Thread` instead of implementing Runnable.
2. change `start` to :

```
public void start(){
    running = true;
    super.start(); // <- note super here
}
```

Optionally add `Override` notation to `start/stop` methods, or rename your `stop` -> `stopTimer`